# what's the advantage of using operator function in Python?

Tags: python

```
from operator import add
n1 = add(2,3)
n2 = 2 + 3
```

Both return exactly the same number and I believe they also work in the same way. What are the advantages of using `add()` to calculate the sum of two numbers?

are there any cases where only one method is accepted?

Comment: The `operator` modules provides functions that are equivalent to the Python operators, for use as, say, arguments to other functions, or places you might use `lambda x, y: x + y`

Comment: You can't do `reduce(add, my_list)` using the plus sign for example.

Comment: Hi,

The operator module provide more functionality than add, sub or mul. You can see a detailed explanation using this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-functions-in-python-set-1/

Comment: operator functonalities tend to be faster than lambda equivalents as well

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you may want to pass the operator as a function somewhere, for example:

```
functools.reduce(operator.mul, [2,3,4,5])  # 120
```

You could, of course do something like:

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [2,3,4,5])
```

but the operator reads better and is faster.